# In flutter mobile app when click on TextBox it's redirect to home page and keyboard crashing issue

Tags: flutter, key

In the flutter mobile app when clicking on TextBox it's redirecting to the home page and the keyboard crashing issue.

Comment: can you include sample code-that will reproduce the error

Comment: Also add flutter log